# Why does my Flask application only work properly on AKS with one replica?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, flask, azure-aks, replicaset

When I deploy a simple flask application on AKS with one replica, the application is running as expected. But when I deploy the application with two replicas, it was not working as expected. User not able to redirect home page post sign in was successful, sometimes it works.

How do we manage the flask application with two replicas?

Here are my kubernetes manifests for your reference.

Thanks

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontpage
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontpage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontpage
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontpage
        image: ***.azurecr.io/frontpage:latest
        limits:
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontpage
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontpage
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontpage
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.***.com
    secretName: ingress-tls-csi
  rules:
  - host: www.***.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontpage
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Does your application manage any state? Can you please provide your deployment, service and input?

Comment: Updated deployment, service and ingress manifests. please check

Comment: Are you using Gunicorn or uwsgi? Can you share the configuration?

Comment: I have deployed simple flask application from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-python&tabs=windows). The application is working as expected with one replica, but with multiple, it doesn't. If User sign in to the page, the page redirects to the same sign in page again.

Comment: Based on the application code, I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the doc, I will change the session backend and try, will update if that works.

Comment: I'm thinking to use Azure SQL database for backend session further, currently configured with redis and encountered by an error saying that, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modified'`. I have updated the `app_config.py` with `import redis` `SESSION_TYPE = "redis"` `SESSION_REDIS = redis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379')`, and the application page shows "Internal Server Error" Any advise please? many thanks in advance

Comment: This is a separate issue.
I'm surprised to see "localhost", I assume you're using an external REDIS and so the URL should be remote.

Comment: I tried using Azure Sql database, but the result is same , the configuration was, `import pyodbc` `SESSION_TYPE = sqlalchemy` `SESSION_SQLALCHEMY = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' 'SERVER=<your_server_name>.database.windows.net;' 'DATABASE=<your_database_name>;' 'UID=<your_username>;' 'PWD=<your_password>;' 'Encrypt=yes;' 'TrustServerCertificate=no;' 'Connection Timeout=30;'
)`

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as a stack trace? Does it work on your laptop?

Comment: Yes, when I use `SESSION_TYPE = filesystem`, it's working as expected and the flask session folder is created locally. As you advised, if I configure the database-backend session, the issue may get fixed.

Comment: With `SESSION_TYPE = SESSION_SQLALCHEMY`, does this work locally?

You can also try creating a share volume between replicas to check the hypothesis and then update the SESSION_TYPE.

Comment: No, It didn't, I tried using Azure Sql database, but the result is same, `import pyodbc` 
 `SESSION_TYPE = "sqlalchemy"`  `SESSION_SQLALCHEMY = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' 'SERVER=<your_server_name>.database.windows.net;' 'DATABASE=<your_database_name>;' 'UID=<your_username>;' 'PWD=<your_password>;' 'Encrypt=yes;' 'TrustServerCertificate=no;' 'Connection Timeout=30;' )`

Comment: Sure, I will try to create share volume between replicas and check the hypothesis. If you have any spec doc, please update, thanks

Comment: I just configured pv and pvc using [Microsoft Spec Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision?tabs=mount-nfs%2Csecret).  Everything looks fine and when I deploy the final step, nginx-blob, I'm getting the error by saying `Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[blob01], unattached volumes=[blob01 kube-api-access-wftpv]: timed out waiting for the condition`

Any help?

Comment: Do you have sufficient authorisation? If so, please provide your code.

Comment: I just fixed it, the resourcegroup was different. Thank you. I followed the [Spec doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision?tabs=mount-nfs%2Csecret) and deployed PV and PVC with blob storage for multiple pods need concurrent access to the same storage volume. Now how should I make it work with two replicas? I have changed the deployment yaml with volume mount, but it didn't work. please advise if you have any idea. Thanks

Comment: Have you changed the SESSION DRIVER?

Comment: No, could you please share the guidelines on this if possible?

Comment: Add to your `app_config.py`, the `SESSION_FILE_DIR` variable with a folder mounted as a volume. The doc link is available in my answer.

Comment: I have updated in answer section with all my configuration. Could you please advise? because I tried using multiple replicas, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` or to add the [captured group](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target).

---

UPDATE

[Your application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/main/app.py) uses a [file system session affinity](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/main/app_config.py) and therefore contains a state (see `SESSION_TYPE`). This state is not shared between your replicas.

Can you change the [session backend](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration)? You can also probably share the backend with a volume between replicas for testing.

Comment: I tried using both annotations with two replicas, `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` and  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` but the page shows **This page isn’t working** or **404 Not Found**. The page is available when I remove the second annotation but the behavior is same. Thanks

Comment: Did you try without annotation?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the nginx controller, but in this case there may not be a first group (because there is no prefix) and so the annotation should be: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I tried without annotation, page can access but the behaviour is same. Also `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` or `$2`  with`path: /(/|$)(.*)` or `path: /(.*)` same. 

The path `path: /(/|$)(.*)` - page can't access, will access only with `path: /(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your update. I have configured **app_config.py**, like

`SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"`

`SESSION_FILE_DIR = "/mnt/blob"`

And updated my `kubernetes manifests` with volume details,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontpage
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontpage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontpage
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontpage
        image: ****.azurecr.io/frontpage:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 1000Gi
          requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
        volumeMounts:
          - name: flask-session-volume
            mountPath: "/mnt/blob"
      volumes:
        - name: flask-session-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-blob
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontpage
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontpage
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontpage
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ***.host.com
    secretName: ingress-tls-csi
  rules:
  - host: ***.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontpage
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Do you have any files written to your volume?

Comment: No, I just deployed as per the [Spec doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision?tabs=mount-nfs%2Csecret)

Comment: I mean "Without replicas, does the application write files to the volume"?

Comment: No, it's not saving any session data

Comment: Can you print the value of `SESSION_FILE_DIR` in the logs to be sure? Are you sure you're using `app_config.py` and not `app_config_b2c.py`? 

Is the application running as root? I think `/mnt` is not accessible to a standard user by default.

Comment: Sure, I tried using Redis, it's working as expected. I just configured `app_config.py` as per the [Session Doc](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration), how Do I keep this in Production environment? because redis server is running locally now. Thanks

Comment: You need to deploy a Redis in your Kubernetes and then update your application's Redis settings to point to it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm able to use Redis as flask session backend. Needs check multiple replicas.

Comment: I have configured my flask application session with Redis on my Aks Cluster. it's working fine and as expected with multiple replicas. Thank you for your support.